# How can I limit ImageField to a few choices in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model like with a file defined like

```
models.ImageField(upload_to='folder_icons', null=True)
```

I want to be able to limit the choice of this icon to a few pre created choices.

I there as way I can show the user (staff member) the choices in the django admin perhaps in a dropdown ?

This is similar to where I want a field where you choose between a few different avatars. Is there a custom field somewhere that can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a starting point, you would need to override the [ModelAdmin.get_form()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method, which will allow you to change the type of input field that Django uses by default for your `image` field. Here's what it should look like:

```
from django.forms import Select

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # 1. Get the form from the parent class:
        form = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        # 2. Change the widget:
        form.base_fields['your_image_field'].widget = Select(choices=(
            ('', 'No Image'),
            ('path/to/image1.jpg', 'Image 1'),
            ('path/to/image2.jpg, 'Image 2'),
        ))

        # 3. Return the form!
        return form
```

You'll still have some other considerations - for instance, the path/location of the images themselves (placing them in the `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` would probably be easiest, or at least the first step in trying to make this work). I can also imagine that you might want a more sophisticated presentation of this field, so that it shows a thumbnail of the actual images (see [@Cheche's answer where he suggests select2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52894438/844976) - that gets a bit more complicated though, as you'll need to craft a custom widget).

All of that said, in terms of just altering the form field that the admin uses so that it offers a dropdown/select field, rather than a file upload field, this is how you would achieve that.

Comment: Thanks. Should the image field widget not expect image data and not a string to the path of an image ?
On submission I get "No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form."

Comment: You know - that is a problem with my answer. Thinking more on your problem, it strikes me that you should probably just be using a select field, and *not* an image field. The image field is specifically designed to provide file saving capabilities, and that's not really something you need - you already have the file(s) uploaded to your server, you just want your admins to be able to choose from a pre-defined list of choices. In that case, you'd want to use models.CharField with the choices kwarg (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Comment: I did this in the end . I changed to a char field and also added another dynamic property that shows the char string as a image. Thanks

Comment: You bet! Glad that worked out, and congrats/nice job on showing the image - the ability to do stuff like that is what I love about Django, it's really flexible once you start poking around under the hood, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `widget` to render your choices. You could try with [select2](https://select2.org) or any django adapt to this, like [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2). Check [this](https://blog.applegrew.com/2012/08/django-select2/).